# Interactive but basic graphics for mysql data

Tags: mysql, charts, visualization

On the web there are many libaries and programs that alow for basic display of data yet there doesn't seem to be one that is able to quickly generate basic x/y graphs based on simple drag/drop input from the mysql database.

Is there a method available opensource/free/paid to get a quick and (if needed) very dirty view of data in a graphical way? 
Preferable it should plug in to Workbench or be a stand alone (web) app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java ,you can refer to http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/ ,if you are using Python , you can refer to http://matplotlib.org/ .